# PHP and Javascript send same random value to server

Tags: javascript, php

I want to set the same random value to both PHP and javascript variable, but when I POST form those random variable is changed.

What I did is:

**`In PHP`**

```
$rand_string = $gen->RandomString(7); //It generate random string

if(isset($_POST['call']))
{
    $toid = $_POST['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $byid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $conn->setNotification($toid,$byid,$username,$rand_string); //It store data in database
}
```

**`In HTML`**

```
<form onsubmit="popitup('calling.php')" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="john" />
  <button class="btn" type="submit" name="call">call</button>
```

**`In javascript`**

```
function popitup(url) {
  var rand_val = '<?php echo $rand_string; ?>';
  newwindow=window.open(url+"?room="+rand_val,'name');
  if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

But In here what happens is, `$rand_string` of sending in a database and sending in javascript new windows is different.
How can I solve that?

Thanks in advance and
sorry for bad English.

Comment: The php at the beginning is the content of `calling.php` ?

Comment: @MickaelLeger No `calling.php` is different , those php content goes to `setNotification.php`.

Comment: i  think its never ever a good idea to mix php code in a js function. i would change the popitup('calling.php') to popitup('calling.php', $rand_string) and then the js function definition to function popitup(url, rand_string) {...}

Comment: So to be sure to understand : You call `setNotification.php` first and generate `$rand_string`. Then when user submit the form you do two things : you use `popitup` to display `$rand_string` and you call `setNotification.php` again to store data in database? I think the fact that the same form do 2 things (store data in php and call a JS function) may generate `$rand_string` twice. Try to check add some `echo $rand_string` and `alert(rand_val)` in your `popitup()` function to see what happen

Comment: @MickaelLeger Yes exactly. Okay I will see, but how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: @FatFreddy I tried this, but It can't popup my javascript new window.

Comment: @PradipDhakal Looks like your `$rand_string` will be regenerated. Can't you just use php session to store the `$rand_string`?

Comment: @MickaelLeger First, `popitup` function is called and after that, PHP `insert` code execute, that's why my random string is different, so how can I solve that?

Comment: You should try to use Ajax to use some JS + insert data in database. The idea : 1/ When user sub form, you do an ajax call to `setNotification.php` : you create the `$rand_string` + insert it to the database. 2/ You send back this `$rand_string` to your JS (just use `echo $rand_string` at the end of the php) and you use this value in the success part of you ajax call. 3/ Now use this value to do what popitup do with the same value. Do you use jQuery so I can try an anwser?

Comment: @DavidDomain Thanks man, It worked for me.

Comment: @MickaelLeger Thanks man, It is great Idea to popup and store data in databse.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the submit the page  calling.php it will change the value in $rand_string variable   so you need to change the code like below

```
      if(isset($_POST['call']))
        {
            $toid = $_POST['id'];
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $byid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $conn->setNotification($toid,$byid,$username,$rand_string); //It store data in database
    $rand_string = $gen->RandomString(7); //It generate random string
    }
else
    {
    $rand_string = $gen->RandomString(7); //It generate random string
    }
```

It will solve your problem